# Using HTTPS for swagger-ui

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, swagger, swagger-ui

My goal is to make Swagger-UI docs available under https. But, as I see know, there is no configuration for that. I tried to find any configuration option in their NuGet package and failed.

Does somebody know any hacks for .Net core to make swagger UI docs displayed under https? (currently, it redirects requests to the HTTP endpoint).

Comment: What web server are you using? Sounds like a web server config issue rather than .NET Core.

Comment: Good question. I'm using dotnetcore 2.0 inside AWS lambda function, and when I try to access swagger route it returns 301(redirect). And I don't understand why...

Comment: Ah. Ok, haven't played with Lambda at all yet. I've done dotnet core on linux behind NGINX before, and I know I had to play around with rewrites. But, can't speak at all to Lambda. Might be worth adding a Lambda tag to your question to get more eyeballs.